# Location of |DataDirectory| in WebApi project/template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I do realize there are many questions here on how to change the value of |DataDirectory|. My question is slightly different.

I realized that if you are using a WebApi project with EntityFramework, then the |DataDirectory| points to the App_Data folder which is created by default. I believe the same is true for an MVC project.

So my question is where can I find the code that has specified App_Data as |DataDirectory| in these standard templates. I just want to use the same code for my class library

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

|DataDirectory| is defined in HttpRuntime class under System.Web assembly.

I decompiled System and System.Web assembly and I found source code for AppDomain class and some DataDirectory related following code.

App_Data is a hard coded string in the assembly. However it can be overridden using AppDomain.CreateDomain() method.

Here is the code I found.

Global variable in HttpRuntime class

```
internal const string DataDirectoryName = "App_Data";
```

And a function in HttpRuntime class

```
private void SetUpDataDirectory()
{
      string path = Path.Combine(this._appDomainAppPath, "App_Data");
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", (object) path, (IPermission) new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, path));
}
```

I found another piece of code in System.Data.Common assembly under DbConnectionOptions.cs file. Here is the code.

```
internal const string DataDirectory = "|datadirectory|";
```

And then I found another code in System.Web.DataAccess assembly under SqlConnectionHelper class. Here is the code.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
internal static string GetDataDirectory()
{
      if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
        return Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data");
      string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path1))
      {
        string path1_1 = (string) null;
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        ProcessModule processModule = currentProcess != null ? currentProcess.MainModule : (ProcessModule) null;
        string path2 = processModule != null ? processModule.FileName : (string) null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path2))
          path1_1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(path2);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path1_1))
          path1_1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        path1 = Path.Combine(path1_1, "App_Data");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", (object) path1, (IPermission) new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, path1));
      }
      return path1;
}
```

This means, |DataDirectory| is defined and used at multiple places. But it's common place to get the data is from HttpRuntime and AppDomain property.

I am using JetBrain's DotPeek to decompile these assemblies. I hope the same helps you.